# Embedded write for denormalizationContext works exactly opposite

Tags: api-platform.com

In my `ManyToOne` relationship between `Vehicle` and `Person` entities I'm trying to implement embedded write for `Vehicle::$owner` (Person entity). But as soon as I add `@Groups` annotation equals to one defined in `denormalizationContext` it completely erases this property at all from the generated JSON for POST operation. I did it several times before and it worked perfectly. I created a project from scratch and found this feature working well. I carefully looked through the annotation code and see no mistakes in it. Any ideas how to debug the issue? May be someone faced with the issue?

Comment: Please share your normalization groups, you will need to create custom data persister for Vehicle Entity as IRI for Person might not exist or vice versa, more context is requierd.

Comment: Hm-m.... Seems like absence (or presence) of related entity is not a problem https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#denormalization: if it exists just add @id, leave it as null if you need create a new one. The main confusion is that the property associated with related entity is wiped out from generated JSON-template of the POST's request body.

Comment: Somewhere group / context doesn't match. Make sure you are using same groups for read/write on both classes. I couldn't reproduce issue with core@2.5.6. Also note that @id is Hydra/HAL context while in normal json you use `id`